# If statement not showing output when true and prints else always

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The if statement is not working when it is true and always shows the output from the else statement

```
else if (dropDown.value === "New") {
        db.collection("testing").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                if (doc.data().userEmail === userEmail.value) {
             
                    promptContent.innerText = "Email already exists"
                }
                else {
                    
                    promptContent.innerText = "Account created."
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

But when I comment out the else statement it shows the right result, but shouldn't else work only if the *if statement* fails?

Comment: You are looping. This condition will be checked many times.

Comment: I need to cross check with email in the db with user's input too before letting them submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

Things you can try:

- trim the strings before comparing

  - "test" will not equal "test " - use `.trim()`
- if the strings are not case sensitive, then match their case before comparing

  - "tEst" will not equal "test" - use `.toLowerCase()`

Comment: This im doing at the time of form submission just so there are no spaces in the data sent to the db